# Unable to open Azure database in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I am unable to open my Azure database in Visual Studio. I create the the database with no problems but when I try to open the database in Visual Studio, a get a blank untitled web page.

I tried clearing the Firewall Settings and reapplying them but that did not help. I downloaded the Data Processing and Storage workloads,to no avail.

Can someone help out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preferred method of connecting to Azure SQL dbs is to use the SQL Server Object Explorer under View --> SQL Server... (or Ctrl+, Ctrl+S):

[image: Visual Studio Enterprise View Pull-down Menu]

The SQL Explorer should appear on the left menu and show any previously connected SQL servers, regardless of their hosting location:

[image: SQL Server Object Explorer]

Press the Server+ icon next to refresh to bring up the server selection dialog. In my particular case, the user account I use for both development/vs licensing and Azure management are the same, so the menu that appears automatically shows all of my accessible Azure DBs, based on my access in Azure.  So the easiest thing to do is add all of your potential MS/work accounts to VS and let it look for the resources for you.

If you select one of your auto-detected DBs, most of the form at the bottom will be filled out for you.  You'll still need to input the password of the DB.  Note that you can switch to different Azure accounts, and select your different Azure subscriptions from within this menu as well:

[image: Microsoft account selection in SQL Server Explorer]

Now, if you don't have a common user account that you can use to automate this process, then you have to just manually fill out the server connection form with the full Azure SQL db address ({server_name}.database.windows.net), the db's admin username and password.  Using either the selection or manual input method, if your DB server has "Deny public network access" enabled, VS should prompt you to create a firewall rule allowing your remote client access to the DB.  But for troubleshooting connection issues, you may want to disable the "Deny public..." option altogether:

[image: Create a new firewall rule]

Comment: This method proved fruitless as well, Tim. First, I click Tools> Connect to Database>, Second, in the Choose Data Source dialogue box, I click Microsoft SQl Server. The next dialogue box - Add Connection> I fill out the database and Server name and when I click Ok, I get the error message I posted in my post above. What did I do wrong?

Comment: That's not following the instructions I provided then. I'm having you use the newer "SQL Server Object Explorer," which has better integration with Azure SQL than the old "Server Explorer" you're attempting to use. Is my option missing from your version of VS? Another way to access it instead of what I provided in screenshots is to use Tools > "Add SQL Server" to bring up the newer workflow.  Also, ensure that you put in the full server address of SERVER_NAME.database.windows.net and select SQL Server Authentication instead of what you have in the screenshot you posted to a later answer.

Comment: Thanks again, Tim. It seems like I got it working now so I can move on to the next step in the project. The problem with me was I mistook in your instructions "Server Explorer" for "Sql Server Object Explorer" (if you can believe it).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new database project in Visual Studio, and then import the existing database to the database project. You need to give server credentials along with database name while importing the database.

Comment: I tried this method and it did not work for me. I am not sure how to import the database from Azure an the only "import" option under tools does not cover databases.

Answer (score 0):

This the error message I am receiving when I attempt to connect my database:

[Testing database connection Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfPOS.png)

Comment: It's generally considered a best practice on these forums to edit your original question to provide further context if you wish to provide it, or if someone asks for clarification or more details.  That way your question doesn't get broken up into different pieces, and it doesn't get listed as an "answer."